# Unable to access returned error response in Axios from Laravel Lumen API

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, lumen

I've got a Laravel Lumen 7 RESTful API alongside a Nuxt JS front-end with Axios. My front-end makes Axios calls to the API and inside of my Lumen project I'm of course returning relevant responses and error codes. However, it appears that these responses although I can see them when I inspect the network and can see it in the preview/response tabs, I'm unable to access it from Axios in my `catch()` block...

If I change it to a `200` response then I can access it from my `then()` block but this isn't ideal.

#### Lumen response

```php
return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => 'We\'re unable to add this domain right now, please try again shortly'], 500);
```

#### JS Axios function

```js
/*
** Add domain
*/
addDomain () {

  // add new domain
  this.$axios.post(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/domains/add`, this.domainCreation).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err) // doesn't display my Object from laravel, instead just the native error string: "Error: Request failed with status code 500"
  })

}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Change status code `to one of 4xx codes`. Also err.response. 500 is reserved for server config errors and you application probably thinks your backend encountered a config error. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this `err.response` catch error data is inside `response`

```js
this.$axios.post(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/domains/add`, this.domainCreation).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response);
  })
```

ref link https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, you should consider returning the correct response codes.

`5xx` error codes are for Internal Server Errors. You are probably looking to return a `422` unprocessable entity error.

More info about 500 status code: https://httpstatuses.com/500

More info about 422 status code: https://httpstatuses.com/422

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. What did was changing my `err` to be `err.response`

Comment: It definitely has to be `err.response`. I did not include it in the answer as I mentioned in the first comment since there was an answer addressing that. I focused more about error codes, but yeah that was not the answer to the question asked I suppose.